# web.py loads the page even when the class is renamed

Tags: python, web.py

I understand that the browser makes an HTTP request to the bin/app.py application and asks for the / URL, which is commonly the first URL on any website.

Inside bin/app.py I have a list of URLs and what classes they match.

The only ones I have are the '/' and 'index' mappings. It's given in *Learn Python the Hard Way* that:

> This means that whenever someone goes to / with a browser, lpthw.web will find the class index and load it to handle the request.

I have the following code in app.py right now.

```
import web
urls = ('/','index')
app = web.application(urls,globals())

class whatever:
    def GET(self):
        a = "Hello World!"
        return a
if __name__ == "__main__":
app.run()
```

In the above code, I named the class "whatever." Even then, when I go to the localhost page, the browser displays "Hello World!"

Why is this happening? Even if I rename one of the urls from "index" to something else, the code works. What am I missing?

Comment: Did you restart the server? Also, are you sure you're editing the right file?

Comment: I have app.py open in one window (IDLE) and the command prompt, from where I executed the code in the other. Is it necessary that I restart the server every time I change a class? @Blender

Comment: Remove all .pyc file if present any...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the server needs to be restarted after every code change. However, there is a workaround. From [the web.py tutorial](http://webpy.org/tutorial2.en):

> ...On the last line add web.reloader so that it reads:
>
> `if __name__ == "__main__": web.run(urls, globals(), web.reloader)`
>
> This tells web.py to use the web.reloader "middleware" (middleware is a wrapper function to add some functionality to your web server) which reloads your files whenever you edit them, so that you can see the changes in your web browser right away. (For some serious changes, though, you'll still have to restart the server.) You'll probably want to take this out when you make your site public, but it's great while developing